# In "The Last Jedi" was it actually Poe's fault that so much of the resistance died?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, poe-dameron

In *The Last Jedi* would Holdo's plan have worked if not for Poe's folly?

> Holdo planned to discreetly evacuate the remaining Resistance members using small transports.  It seemed to me that the reason many of them got blown out of space was because when Finn and Rose got caught that guy DJ told the enemy about the escape transports.  Somehow the bad guys didn't see them until DJ told them to look.  So the transports could have evaded the bad guys had Poe not hatched that sabotage plan.

What I'm asking is, did everyone else see it that way?  The First Order would not have seen the small transports if DJ didn't alert them about it?  Or did I miss something?  If, so, really?  Poe could disobey orders, mutiny, fail, get more than half his comrades killed and that's OK because he meant well.

Comment: What exactly are you asking: Was it Poe's fault? Or, why wasn't Poe punished?

Comment: Well was Poe not punished because the First Order could have seen the transports anyway?  Or was it really only because Poe's away team got caught that the first order saw the transports?  But no one felt any need to point that out to Poe?

Comment: I do not agree that it is a duplicate.

Comment: Nah, the plot is absurd. Poe sacrificed a few bombers to take out a huge capitol ship. That's a win in any war. If he hadn't done that, there is a good chance it would have been able to fire on the fleet (which if they were sane, they would have done in the first place rather shooting the already evacuated base).

Comment: Yes, Poe was a hero earlier on.  I guess no one is going to answer a simple question.  Was there any indication that the First Order could have seen the escape transports if DJ hadn't informed them?

Comment: @Harabeck If those are the only bombers you have left, it's not necessarily a win. It all hinges on what damage that thing would have done. The problem is, it all reeks of weak plot, in which people act the way they do because the story demands it, making it hard to actually reason about what would have happened, if someone acted differently as they don't act very comprehensible in the first place (and the situation is somewhat absurd given other movies, e.g. what happened to Y-wings?! why are those bombers so slow etc.).

Comment: And as far as an answer goes (I don't agree it's a duplicate either, but it's highly related), Poe could not have told DJ the plan as he only learned of the plan afterwards anyway. So why or what DJ exactly tells the First Order is a bit unclear to me. He might tell the First Order that the Resistance has cloaking technology on their small crafts. It would be a bit weird that they wouldn't know. To me that looks as a plot hole. Maybe I'm overlooking something that would indicate what exactly he could have told them, but it would not particularly stand out as a plot hole in this movie...

Comment: Side note: The whole botching up of plans, ignoring orders, being a terrible leader topic involving Poe, Leia, Holdo isn't resolved/discussed at all although it could in principle be a great piece of character development for all of them.

Comment: And with regard to punishment, there is barely any time to punish anyone even if they wanted to for some reason once they get shot at. Not to mention they at first don't know why they are being discovered and it's unclear when or what Finn and Rose report later on - in the middle of their struggle to stay alive.